# Joda DateTimeFormatter fails only when run by Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jodatime

This is an odd one. My Joda DateTimeFormatter based parser works perfectly unless it's run by Jenkins. I can even log onto the jenkins, as the jenkins user, and successfully run the tests.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS MMM dd yyyy");

public static DateTime datetime(String timeStamp, String timeZone) {
  return TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone))
                         .parseDateTime(timeStamp)
                         .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
}

@Test public void getDatetime() {
  assertEquals(new DateTime("2013-01-01T00:35:18.146Z")
    .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC), datetime("00:35:18.146 JAN 01 2013", "GMT"));
}
```

When run by Jenkins I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "00:35:18.146 JAN
>   01 2013" is malformed at "JAN 01 2013"

Comment: What's your project's Jenkins setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a locale problem. It will throw such exception if the default locale is not English. Please check Jenkins default locale.

By the way, you can also change your code: add `withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)` to the formatter.

```
public static DateTime datetime(String timeStamp, String timeZone) {
    return TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone))
            .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
            .parseDateTime(timeStamp)
            .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
}
```

Comment: Superb, that was it. While the server was English, Jenkins was French.